# How to force read and write to file that is located in C:\?

Tags: c#, security

In my program I work with a text file that I save in 'c:\'

On some computers the program can't save to 'c:\' because of security issues.

How can I make it so that I can read/write/save my file to 'c:\'?

Answer (score 7):

The right answer is of course: Don't do that.

Use a folder that will work for everybody, like

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you ought to read the [Namespace Usage Guidelines](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=88ad7e7c-4068-48b8-9503-e160a6693bba) and read/write the file in an appropriate location. The root of the C drive isn't the right answer for any file.

Answer (score 2):

There is a reason, why you can't write there. Write in the users home folder, instead. If you really need to write to C:\, you will require elevation for Windows Vista and greater. Try searching google or SO about it.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is with UAC under Windows 7 or Vista [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista-security/MakingAppsUACAware.aspx?msg=2623884) can help you.
Otherwise someone has to disable the UAC maybe your program with sufficient privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Start your app with Admin privileges, or make your program require them to start.
[How to do it](http://www.aneef.net/2009/06/29/request-uac-elevation-for-net-application-managed-code/)

Or, another way: Do not do so. Store you data in C:\Users[User]\AppData\